# WCF Service Backwards Compatibility Check

Tags: wcf, web-services, metadata, versioning, backwards-compatibility

I have just written a new version of a WCF web service and I want to make sure that I have not made any breaking changes with regard to Service and Data contracts.

Thinking back to my days as a VB6 Com Api developer I recall how easy it was to specify the previous release version of the component at compile time, and have the compiler check that binary compatibility is being maintained.

I envisage something similar called (hopefully) a “Contract Compatibility” check. It would use the metadata to perform a similar check to the one that the VB6 dev env did. This could be done as a separate build step that would execute a utility.

I am prepared to accept that there exists no such utility out there. If that is the case, does anyone have any ideas about how the algorithm to achieve this would look?

1. Retrieve metadata from current live service version
2. Retrieve meta data from new service version
3. Check Service Contract and each Data Contract for compatibility. Only reporting breaking changes.

Step 3 seems like it would be complex but certainly automatable...

Comment: If there are compatibility issues, you can use the service contract's namespace for versioning, and keep both versions available until you're sure the old one isn't being used any more.

Answer (score 4):

These situations are solved by integration/regression testing. You write integration tests for initial version and after modifying service to new version you run integration tests again using old client. If they success you didn't break anything. If they fail you see exactly what calls caused problems.

Comment: Good point. That would do the trick. If a static check is not possible then a runtime check would be the next best thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like that exists Andy but if you get something up and running whereby you have 2 DLLs (one old and one new), you could then use something like BitDiffer to compare them.

There was a project on Codeplex that helped with WCF releases, but I can't remember what it is called, sorry.

Good luck,

-Keith

Comment: Also you may try to compare 2 DLLs using ApiChange, LibCheck or NDepend tools.

Answer (score 0):

See ["Versioning WCF Services: Part I"](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/versioning-wcf-services-part-i.aspx) and ["Versioning WCF Services: Part II"](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/net-framework2/versioning-wcf-services-part-ii.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate unit tests using ["Codeplex WCF Load Test"](http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/) for old interface contract and run them on a new one:

> This tool takes a WCF trace file and a WCF client proxy, or a WCF interface contract, and generates a C# unit test that replays the same sequence of calls found in the trace file. The unit test can then be used to load-test the target.